# remove characters from a list and add a line break from each element

Tags: python

I'm working on a project in which I must create some objects for this use a dictionary in which the objects are saved with their identifier, now, I need that only appears the attribute of the objects, without needing the identifier, for this convert the values of the dictionary in a list, but I can not remove things like [ ] or give line breaks

my code is:

```
class myclass():
   
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x 




    list_obj = [] 
    list_attrs = []
    list_values = []
    for i in range (3):
        obj = myclass(' U')
        y= list_obj.append(obj)
        b=list(y.b())
        list_values.append(b)
        

print(list_values)
```

my output is:

```
['U'], ['U'], ['U']]
```

Any idea how to do this?.I tried to use strip but it doesn't give me the desired result or I even thought of converting the whole list into a string and maybe I could do it, but I can't get it.

Comment: If you've "heard of" `strip()` maybe you should look it up in the documentation.

Comment: I think it's obvious that I've been looking for this for half the afternoon, but it's generating errors or it's just not working for me, that's why this is the question on the forum. I consider that nobody comes here to ask without first trying on their own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First flatten the list, then combine each element of the list with a line break as an seperator. You get a string, and if you print it it looks like you expect it.

```
lst = [['Ultra1', 'Max1', 3], ['Ultra2', 'Max2', 3], ['Ultra3', 'Max3', 3]]
string = "\n".join([str(item) for sublist in lst for item in sublist])
print(string)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are **not** printing a string, you are printing a list. Python print has a built in feature to print list like that. To format list in other ways you can check out this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-lists-in-python-4-different-ways/

One way to do what you want:

```
for v in list_values:
    print(*v, sep='\n')
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, it's true what you say and it works perfectly, now, the problem is that the purpose of having the output in that form is not to print on the screen, but, it is to be recorded as it is in a txt file (the printing on the screen is simply to avoid opening the txt file every time I compile), I know how to record it in the file but not how to pass it in that order as you indicate

Comment: Formally this is the correct answer to the question: "and I'd like to see something like this" which is why i upvoted.